# how to add distinct on one column for the ListResponse Grid in Serentiy.is

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serenity-platform

I am using Serene framework from Serenity.is

I am trying to add "DISTINCT" flag into the one column of the query that fetch the data for the grid
I went to the List function of my Endpoint of the table and added the column name "URN" as a distinct field but that didn't have the expected result:

```
public ListResponse<MyRow> List(IDbConnection connection, ListRequest request,
        [FromServices] IClinicalNotesListHandler handler)
    {
        request.DistinctFields = new SortBy[] { new SortBy("URN")} ;
        
        return handler.List(connection, request);
    }
```

Current result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100
T0.[URN] AS [Urn]
FROM [Clinical_Notes] T0
ORDER BY T0.[URN]
```

Expected result:

```
SELECT TOP 100
DISTINCT  T0.[URN] AS [Urn]
,T0.[NoteType] As [Note Type] // and other fields in the table
.....
FROM [Clinical_Notes] T0
ORDER BY T0.[URN]
```

Could someone please help me with this?